# error C3698: 'CreerLevel::Mur ^' : impossible d'utiliser ce type comme argument de 'nouveau'

Tags: c++-cli

i have create one class and i need to use it with vector.

```
    ref class Mur
{
public:
 int debutX, debutY;
 int finX, finY;
 Mur (){}
 Mur(int debutX, int debutY) {
  this->debutX = debutX;
  this->debutY = debutY;
  finX = 0;
  finY = 0;
 }
 ~Mur()
  {
  }
 int getX() { return debutX; }
 int getY() { return debutY; }

 bool estFinit() {
  return (finX==0);
 }

 void finir(int x, int y){
  finX = x;
  finY = y;
 }
};
}
```

When i try to use it

```
 std::vector<Mur^> vMurs;
...
  vMurs.push_back(gcnew Mur(i,j));
```

Error come in file "xmemory" at line 52 but i don't know this file xD

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to use managed handles in (unmanaged) vectors. use `array<Mur^>` instead.

Comment: I highly suggest against using localized development tools. Using them in English means not having to deal with mis- or bad translations, and being able to find much more help through search engines if you run into a problem (like now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Alexandre C.  If you want to use a vector, you could use the STL/CLR (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385954.aspx) vector.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is objecting because you're trying to store a managed object in an unmanaged class.  That cannot work, the garbage collector needs to be able to find object references so it can properly collect garbage.  And since it cannot find unmanaged objects, it cannot find the managed reference either.

I'd strongly advice to not use STL/CLR, it combines all the disadvantages of STL with those of the CLR.  If you really, really want to use vector<> then gcroot<> can solve the problem.  However, using System::Collections::Generic::List<> is by far the best solution.

```
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
...
  List<Mur^>^ vMurs = gcnew List<Mur^>;
...
  vMurs->Add(gcnew Mur(i, j));
```

Comment: I have been having a lot of problems with `using namespace System::Collections::Generic` because of the name clashing (even when not using namespace `System::Collections` alongside). If you run into trouble with this (excellent) solution, remember to only `using namespace System::Collections` and explicitly qualify generic collections (eg. `Generic::List<Mur^>^ vMurs = gcnew Generic::List<Mur^>`)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
std::vector<gcroot<Mur ^> > vMurs;
...
vMurs.push_back(gcnew Mur(i,j));
```

Comment: I don't like mixing managed and non managed types for no valid reason.

Comment: @Alexandre C.: std::vector already is an unmanaged type...so they are already mixed...

Comment: i mean i don't like `gcroot` where not necessary. I'd rather use `List<Mur^>^` for instance. You cannot put vMur inside a managed class too.